# Throw exception if a json input from FormDataBodyPart/Jackson if a date doesn't contain a timezone

Tags: java, json, datetime, jackson, jersey-2.0

Let's say I have a POST request with attachment in using Jersey Framework.
From my Jersey endpoint, i get a FormDataBodyPart, which contains that json string:

```
    {   
    "aField": "aValue",
    "aSecondField":"anotherValue",
    "collectionDate" : {
        "firstDate" : "2019-07-15",
        "secondDate" : "2019-07-15T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

When I deserialize that json into a Java Object, the firstDate field reflect another date because it didnt have a timezone (2019-07-14T22:00:00.000Z).

```
formDataBodyPartData.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
EntityExample entityExample = formDataBodyPartData.getValueAs(EntityExample.class);
```

So I'd like to force users to put the timezone information in each date.
Is it possible ? (I can have a solution based on Jackson too).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT :

The collectionDate class has the following schema and unfortunately I can't change it.

```
public class CollectionDate{
 private java.util.Date firstDate;
 private java.util.Date secondDate;
....
}
```

So I'd like a solution in order to restrict the unmarschalling of the json string when i use that line :

```
formDataBodyPartData.getValueAs(..)
```

I can have as well a solution based on Jackson, for instance :

```
EntityExample entityExample = objectMapper.readValue(value, EntityExample.class);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for mapping  both `firstDate` and `secondDate` properties. The deserialization will fail when the input doesn't match the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME) pattern:

```java
@Data
public class CollectionDate {
    private OffsetDateTime firstDate;
    private OffsetDateTime secondDate;
}
```

To use Jackson as JSON provider for JAX-RS, you must add the [`jackson-jaxrs-json-provider`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-providers) artifact as dependency.

And you will also need to register the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) in the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). It can be done in a [`ContextResolver<T>`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html):

```java
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        this.mapper = createObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }

    private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, for some reason I need to keep the java.util.Date class, so is there another possible solution in order to restrict date values without timezone and/or without time information based on my above example ? I'll update my question in order to be more clear.

Comment: @SlimSoltaniDridi `java.util.Date` is considered a _legacy class_ since the JDK 8 release. So you are no longer supposed to use `Date` and their friends, including `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. If you need interoperability with the legacy classes, use `Date.from(OffsetDateTime.now().toInstant())`.

Comment: I know. I'd like to use your solution but in the deserialization thing. So If I can customize that, I just want to know how I can do it from the objectMapper.readValue or formDataBodyPartData.getValueAs.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom deserializer is the main solution but it doesnt fit to my project.

Anyway, this solution works :

Create a custom deserializer like below :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public final class FlexDateDeserialiser extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(final JsonParser parser, final DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

        final String date = parser.getText();
        try {
            return formatter.parse(date);
        } catch (final ParseException ex) {
            throw new IOException("Exemple date");
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates

http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/033-custom-jackson-date-deserializer/

We can use that custom deserializer directly in the POJO :

```
 public class CollectionDate{
 @JsonDeserialize(using = FlexDateDeserialiser.class) private java.util.Date firstDate;
 @JsonDeserialize(using = FlexDateDeserialiser.class) private java.util.Date secondDate;
....
}
```